# Programmatically create an attribute map for custom fields on the lead/contact entities

Tags: c#, mapping, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

So I have a CRM integration that adds two fields to the lead and contact. An integer and a Boolean. When we convert a lead into a contact I want those custom fields from the lead to carry over to the new contact. We have over 700 instances using our product so this needs to be a programmatic solution. And thats where the problem lies. I haven't been able to wrap my head around the CreateAttributeMappings class and was hoping someone here could enlighten me and show me where I'm being dumb...

Right now I've got something like this:

```
var parentEntityMapId = new v4.Sdk.Lookup();
parentEntityMapId.name = "lead";
parentEntityMapId.Value = Guid.NewGuid();

var entityMapId = new v4.Sdk.Lookup();
entityMapId.name = "contact";
//entityMapId.Value = new Guid("608861bc-50a4-4c5f-a02c-21fe1943e2cf");
entityMapId.Value = Guid.NewGuid();

var attributeMapId = new v4.Sdk.Key();
attributeMapId.Value = Guid.NewGuid();

var attributeMap = new v4.SdkTypeProxy.attributemap();
attributeMap.attributemapid = attributeMapId;
attributeMap.entitymapid = entityMapId;
attributeMap.sourceattributename = fieldNameFrom;
attributeMap.targetattributename = fieldNameTo;
//parentEntityMapId.Value = new Guid("DC6574CB-92CE-446C-A5D6-885A75107D52");
attributeMap.parentattributemapid = parentEntityMapId;

var targetAttributeMap = new v4.SdkTypeProxy.TargetCreateAttributeMap();

targetAttributeMap.AttributeMap = attributeMap;

var attributeMapCreateRequest = new v4.SdkTypeProxy.CreateRequest();
attributeMapCreateRequest.Target = targetAttributeMap;

var response = this.CrmService.Execute(attributeMapCreateRequest);
```

However this gives me this error message:

0x80046203
  Invalid mapping. Either an attribute is not mappable, or attributes are of different types, or the size of the target attribute is smaller than the size of the source attribute.
  Platform

Any help or insight you could give me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Need to pull the existing entity map and then just add the two fields and send the request. Something so simple was so frustrating...

```
    public void CreateAttributeMapping(string fieldNameFrom, string entityNameFrom, string fieldNameTo, string entityNameTo)
    {
        var entityMap = Retrieve("entitymap", new List<FilterCriteria> { new FilterCriteria("targetentityname", entityNameTo), new FilterCriteria("sourceentityname", entityNameFrom) }, null);

        var entityMapId = new v4.Sdk.Lookup();
        entityMapId.name = entityMap.GetKeyName();
        entityMapId.Value = entityMap.GetKeyValue();

        var attributeMap = new v4.SdkTypeProxy.attributemap();
        attributeMap.entitymapid = entityMapId;
        attributeMap.sourceattributename = fieldNameTo;
        attributeMap.targetattributename = fieldNameFrom;

        var targetAttributeMap = new v4.SdkTypeProxy.TargetCreateAttributeMap();

        targetAttributeMap.AttributeMap = attributeMap;

        var attributeMapCreateRequest = new v4.SdkTypeProxy.CreateRequest();
        attributeMapCreateRequest.Target = targetAttributeMap;

        var response = this.CrmService.Execute(attributeMapCreateRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say i've done this programmatically myself but what your doing looks correct in terms of creating an `attributemap` which links the fields across both entities.

The error your getting will be one of two things.

The attributemaps fields it's matching from and to may differ either in size or type. This is seems unlikely if you say your integration takes care of the creation but it's probably worth going into CRM through the interface. Finding the relationship between lead and contact, then adding the mapping manually to see if you get the same error.

If you do get an error, then there is something different(type or size).

If you don't get the error, then it means what your trying to do is correct, however there will be an issue in the code somewhere in terms of the attribute map it is trying to create.

In which case it may be worth debugging through to find out more. Then if you look at the values you are trying to set through code, and compare to the one that would now exist in the database from your manual entry it may point to what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

We could do this using PowerShell:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Xrm.Data.Powershell

function Get-EntitymapDetails() {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $SourceEntityName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $TargetEntityName
    )

    $fetchxml = @"
        <fetch>
          <entity name="entitymap" >
            <attribute name="sourceentityname" />
            <attribute name="targetentityname" />
            <attribute name="entitymapidunique" />
            <attribute name="entitymapid" />
            <filter>
              <condition attribute="sourceentityname" operator="eq" value="lead" />
              <condition attribute="targetentityname" operator="eq" value="contact" />
            </filter>
          </entity>
        </fetch>
"@

    $relMappings = (Get-CrmRecordsByFetch -Fetch $fetchxml -AllRows).CrmRecords

    if($relMappings.Count -ne 1) {
        throw "Expected single entity-map - found $($relMappings)"
    }

    $relMappings
}

function Test-AttributeMappingExists() {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [Guid] $EntityMapId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $SourceAttribute,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $TargetAttribute
    )

    $fetchxml = @"
        <fetch >
          <entity name="attributemap" >
            <attribute name="attributemapid" />
            <filter>
              <condition attribute="entitymapid" operator="eq" value="$EntityMapId" />
              <condition attribute="sourceattributename" operator="eq" value="$SourceAttribute" />
              <condition attribute="targetattributename" operator="eq" value="$TargetAttribute" />
            </filter>
          </entity>
        </fetch>
"@


    $attrMappings = (Get-CrmRecordsByFetch -Fetch $fetchxml)

    return ($attrMappings.CrmRecords.Count -gt 0)
}

function Setup-AttributeMapping() {
   param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [Guid] $EntityMapId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $SourceAttribute,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $TargetAttribute
    )

    ## verify that this attribute mapping is not already defined
    $attrMappingExits = Test-AttributeMappingExists `
                            -EntityMapId $entityMap.entitymapid `
                            -SourceAttribute $SourceAttribute `
                            -TargetAttribute $TargetAttribute

    if($attrMappingExits){

        Write-Host "Attribute-Mapping for '$sourceAttr' -> '$targetAttr' is already defined"
        return
    }

    $response = New-CrmRecord -EntityLogicalName 'attributemap' -Fields @{
        entitymapid = New-CrmEntityReference -EntityLogicalName 'entitymap' -Id $EntityMapId
        sourceattributename = $SourceAttribute;
        targetattributename = $TargetAttribute;
    }

    if($response -eq $null) {
        throw $conn.LastCrmError
    }

    Write-Host "Created new attribute-mapping"

}

$conn = Get-CrmConnection -InteractiveMode

$sourceAttr = 'parentaccountid'
$targetAttr = 'parentcustomerid'

$entityMap = Get-EntitymapDetails -SourceEntityName 'lead' -TargetEntityName 'contact'


Setup-AttributeMapping `
    -EntityMapId $entityMap.entitymapid `
    -SourceAttribute $sourceAttr `
    -TargetAttribute $targetAttr
```